# How to get everything in address bar in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url

I have a wordpress link, http://localhost/aircargo/lounge/#314, and I want to get only 314 in its page.

I've tried:

```
get_site_url(),current_page_url(),get_home_url()
```

But I couldn't get id, how to do it?

Comment: you should not get #314 it should be 314 only

Comment: How can I get 314? I dont want to get #314

Comment: Actually link is 'http://localhost/aircargo/lounge' . I would like to pass post id along with the link and want to get that id in the same page. Is there any  way to get it?

Comment: first you have to check why are you getting #314 in the url its wrong put the snippet of that code from which you get #314

Comment: Thank you...  Now I got /aircargo/lounge/314/ . How can I extract 314 from  it

Comment: @cd8xitech putting this solution in the answer plz accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to get the page slug based on your url structure.
You can use [get_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/) and extract the post name

```
$current_post= get_post( get_the_ID() ); 
$slug = $current_post->post_name;
echo $slug;

##or Must be inside the loop
global $post;
$post_slug=$post->post_name;
echo $post_slug;
```

If that won't work as you might have custom permalink structure then you can just parse the url and extract the last element of path

```
$data = parse_url('http://localhost/aircargo/lounge/314');
$path = explode('/', $data['path']);
echo '<pre>', print_r( end($path), 1), '</pre>';
##output is 314
```

Comment: Its working... Thank you...........